# VC++ 2010 C2061 error

Tags: visual-c++

I am getting VC++ 2010 C2061 error on line:

```
#include "queryevaluator_p.h"

class QueryEvaluator {
public:
    vector<AttrValue>* getCandidateList(QueryClause cl, int pos, ResultSet *computedRes);
...
```

> `Error    41  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ResultSet'  h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\code\source\includes\queryevaluator.h 40`

`ResultSet` is a struct defined in "queryevaluator_p.h"

```
struct ResultSet{ //a set of result
    bool valid;
    vector<ResultRow> rows;
};
```

Whats wrong here? ResultSet can be used elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have circular includes (`queryevaluator_p.h` includes the main header again) causing confusion. Depending on the exact setup this can lead to such an effect, because one of the files will have to be compiled first.

The solution would be to resolve the circular dependency by using a forward declaration instead of an include in one place. For example you could forward declare `struct ResultSet` instead of including the `queryevaluator_p.h` header.